# How to use writeString( ) method to put quotes around a name the user inputs from a dialog box?

Tags: java, string, quotes

In my project I am taking the data the user enters and I output it to a txt file. I've got the project done other than I need the employee name the user enters in the dialog box to be in quotes when it is output to the dialog box. Can someone direct me how to do this?

This is my code:

```
public class OutputToAFileBrocEast
{   
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try {
            File file = new File("payroll.txt");      

            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());

            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

            String name;
            String rate;
            String hours;
            String answer;

            do {

                name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter first and last name: ");
                rate = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter hourly rate: ");
                hours = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter hours for previous week: ");

                bw.write(name);
                bw.write(rate);
                bw.write(hours);
                bw.write("\n");

                answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Do you have another employee? [y/n]");

            } while (answer.equalsIgnoreCase ("y"));

            bw.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To print a ", you need to type \ before it. Exemple: System.out.println("\"" + employename + "\"");

Comment: If I understand you correctly all you need to do is change `bw.write(name);` to `bw.write("\""+name+"\"");` the \ is an escape character that will then print the double quote normally instead of using it to end the string.

Comment: I hope you realise that you write everything as one long string...

Answer (score 3):

**[edited with spaces prepended to the quote-enclosed values]**

If you need to enclose the `name` String in double quotes in your text file, you can either:

- `bw.write("\"" + name + "\" ");`
- `bw.write(String.format("\"%s\" ", name));`
- `bw.write(new StringBuilder("\"").append(name).append("\" ").toString());`
- etc...

The back-slash character `\` before a double-quote escapes it.

Comment: Mena, I noticed another problem, could you possibly assist with how I can get spaces after each input in the txt file? Basically what is happening now is unless I type a space in the dialog box after the input, it does not put a space in between the different values entered by the user.

Comment: @user3485794 sure let me edit my answer - it's the same principle.

Answer (score 2):

you can escape the quotes using backslash as shown below:

```
\"
System.out.println("\"Something\"");
```

will print

```
"Something"
```

The rest is just concatenating strings, which you can do in every way you want.